# Divide windows form into 4 section and view diffrent orientation panel in each section

Tags: .net, panel, flip, inverse, external-process

I want to develop the windows desktop application(.NET) for the large all in one touch screen.
the screen must be divided into 4 section and lower sections view as normally and upper section view as **flipped(reversed)**.
because we have 2 user that works with the screen simultaneously in front of each other.
we have 4 panels into one form and in each panel may run **any executable file**(like browsers and etc).
could you help me how can i do this scenario as well in the right and optimized way.
Many thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a horrendous idea. Why not use two screens on the one computer? Also, you're going to have fun hosting any arbitrary program in a .NET window. I'd be looking at C++ if I wanted to do that (plus a lot of manual reading about Win32 programming).

Comment: Our Employer wants us to use with one screen and we can't change this condition.

Comment: That's tough, then, as I don't believe that it can be done. Well, anything can be done, but some things will just cost too much. You have two problems: the flipped windows, and each window hosting any random program. I would not actually try to do either.

Comment: You're in a bad position then. Hope it works out OK for you....